# Crop Image from Camera in Swift without move to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, image, crop

I have an image overlay inside CameraViewController:

[image: description]
I want to get the image from inside this red square.
I don't want to move to another view controller to setup a CropViewController, the crop should be done inside this Controller.

This code behind almost works, the problem is that the image generated from camera is 1080x1920 and the self.cropView.bounds is (0,0,185,120) and of course it do not represent the same scale used to take the image

```
extension UIImage {
    func crop(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        var rect = rect
        rect.origin.x*=self.scale
        rect.origin.y*=self.scale
        rect.size.width*=self.scale
        rect.size.height*=self.scale

        let imageRef = self.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know the coordinates of the CGRect you want to crop, use the CIPerspectiveCorrection filter. I'll throw out some code in a few minutes.

Comment: @dfd I am trying to see how CIPerspectiveCorrection works, if you provide any code, will help a lot! Thanks

Comment: I just added it. Copy/pasted from a working app into a new project and it looks like it's working - it looks like it appearing upside down, which is probably due to some point CGPoint transposing. Tell you what, I'll throw my **very beta** app out in a public GitHub.

Comment: okay, repository out there. pretty large, as i have several test images and the like. also it has some animation in it (which means in the simulator is runs very slow) to teach me on the crop/zoom. anyways, it's at [link]https://github.com/justdfd/thefinedetails. hope this helps!

Comment: found it. i'm adding this to my solution, as I'd like to format things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always crop visually any image in a quadrilateral (a four sided shape - doesn't have to be rectangle) using a Core Image filter call CIPerspectiveCorrection.

Let's say you have an imageView frame that is 414 width by 716 height, with an image that is 1600 width by 900 height in size. (You are using a content mode of .aspectFit, right?) Let's say you want to crop a 4 sided shape that's corners - in (X,Y) coordinates in the imageView - are (50,50), (75,75), (100,300), and (25,200). Note that I'm listing the points in top left (TL, top right (TR), bottom right (BR), bottom left (BL) order. Also note that this is not a straight forward rectangle.

What you need to do is this:

1. Convert the UIImage to a CIImage where the "extent" is the UIImage size,
2. Convert those UIImageView coordinates to CIImage coordinates,
3. pass them and the CIImage into the CIPerspectiveCorrection filter for cropping, and
4. render the CIImage output into a UIImageView.

The below code is a little rough around the edges, but hopefully you get the concept:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let uiTL = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
    let uiTR = CGPoint(x: 75, y: 75)
    let uiBL = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 300)
    let uiBR = CGPoint(x: 25, y: 200)

    var ciImage:CIImage!
    var ctx:CIContext!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ctx = CIContext(options: nil)
        ciImage = CIImage(image: imageView.image!)
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        let ciTL = createVector(createScaledPoint(uiTL))
        let ciTR = createVector(createScaledPoint(uiTR))
        let ciBR = createVector(createScaledPoint(uiBR))
        let ciBL = createVector(createScaledPoint(uiBL))
        imageView.image = doPerspectiveCorrection(CIImage(image: imageView.image!)!,
                                                  context: ctx,
                                                  topLeft: ciTL,
                                                  topRight: ciTR,
                                                  bottomRight: ciBR,
                                                  bottomLeft: ciBL)
    }
    func doPerspectiveCorrection(
        _ image:CIImage,
        context:CIContext,
        topLeft:AnyObject,
        topRight:AnyObject,
        bottomRight:AnyObject,
        bottomLeft:AnyObject)
        -> UIImage {
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPerspectiveCorrection")
            filter?.setValue(topLeft, forKey: "inputTopLeft")
            filter?.setValue(topRight, forKey: "inputTopRight")
            filter?.setValue(bottomRight, forKey: "inputBottomRight")
            filter?.setValue(bottomLeft, forKey: "inputBottomLeft")
            filter!.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            let cgImage = context.createCGImage((filter?.outputImage)!, from: (filter?.outputImage!.extent)!)
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
    }

    func createScaledPoint(_ pt:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        let x = (pt.x / imageView.frame.width) * ciImage.extent.width
        let y = (pt.y / imageView.frame.height) * ciImage.extent.height
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
    func createVector(_ point:CGPoint) -> CIVector {
        return CIVector(x: point.x, y: ciImage.extent.height - point.y)
    }
    func createPoint(_ vector:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: vector.x, y: ciImage.extent.height - vector.y)
    }

}
```

EDIT: I'm putting this here to explain things. The two of us swapped projects, and there was an issue with the questioner's code where a nil return was happening. First, here's the corrected code, which should be in the `cropImage()` function:

```
let ciTL = createVector(createScaledPoint(topLeft, overlay: cameraView, image: image), image: image)
let ciTR = createVector(createScaledPoint(topRight, overlay: cameraView, image: image), image: image)
let ciBR = createVector(createScaledPoint(bottomRight, overlay: cameraView, image: image), image: image)
let ciBL = createVector(createScaledPoint(bottomLeft, overlay: cameraView, image: image), image: image)
```

The issue is with the last two lines, which were transposed by passing bottomLeft where it should have been bottomRight, and vice-versa. (Easy mistake to make, I've done it too!)

Some explanation to help those who use CIPerspectiveCorrection (and other filters that use CIVectors).

1. A CIVector can have anywhere from - I think 2 to, well, almost infinite amount of components. It depends on the filter. In this case there are two components (X, Y). Simple enough, but the twist is that the 4 CIVectors describe 4 points inside the CIImage extent where the origin is the bottom left, not the top left.
2. Note I did not say a 4 sided shape. You can actually have a "figure 8" like shape where the "bottom right" point is left of the "bottom left" point! This would result in a shape where two sides cross each other.
3. All that matters is that all 4 points lie with the CIImage extent. If they don't, the filter with return nil for it's output image.

One last note for those who haven't work with CIImage filters before - the filters will not execute until you ask for the outputImage. You can instantiate one, fill in the parameters, chain them, whatever. You can even make a typo in the filter name (or any of their keys). Until your code asks for the filter.outputImage, nothing happens.

Comment: really thanks for the code and sample, but I am still getting a nil image in context.createCGImage, I also just uploaded a sample with the problem https://bitbucket.org/marckaraujo/how-much, I really apreciate your help

Comment: I'm looking at your code now and have it narrowed down to createScaledPoint(). Basically, your CIImage has an extent of 1920x1080, but the conversion of CGPoint(307,240) becomes a vector of (2456,-1080). I'll see if I can come up with why. CIVectors here are basically coordinates where the origin is in the bottom left instead of top left. My routine used global variables and I'm wondering if what you are passing in for the UIImage ("rect" in your code) isn't the **entire** UIImage but something else.

Comment: really thanks, for all your help. It works now, but only without auto-layout. If you use auto-layout, the cropped image was not what you have selected

Comment: interesting. that should not matter.

Comment: I just updated the git if you wanna take a look, I am trying to figure out what happen.

Comment: i'll look at the code tomorrow. one question - assuming you've properly cropped the section of the **full screen** image, where are you looking to display it? in the same superview? another view controller? in the cropView (at which point what should the cameraView look like? or in the cameraView? i'm not really visualizing that part of things.

Comment: I was saving it to photo library, but in the demo I just set up a view of the same size of the cropView, so the cropped image should look exactly as the resultImage.

Comment: ok. i'll look at things later this morning. my app in the app store doesn't use CIPerspectiveCorrection (one other CI and three custom filters though), but it is universal, all orientations, AutoLayout (in code due to certain IB weaknesses) and saves to several things including the photo library. are you using a UIActionSheet? if not, i'd recommend at least looking into it.

Comment: Found it. The problem was with the CIImage, the explanation is here: https://github.com/FlexMonkey/CIImage-UIImage-Orientation-Fix

Comment: He's good. I reference his stuff all the time. I had a scaled-down version of this in my app already, with a // TO DO: to drill into testing it more deeply. Looks like he did it for me! Thanks for the link, and glad I could help you out.